# How to keep Text data consistent in IOS app and website ?

Tags: php, ios, json, parsing, web

Its known fact that we can use Json/XML parsing or Database to maintain a limited amount of data consistent on a given application and Website at any given time.

However, the dilemma is a project having few display textlines 3k-4k that are supposed to be consistent on both(App and website)on a selected UI, these text files may change at any given point of time. What will be the optimized method or steps of implementation for this technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my bit would be to store the data in on server as a text file and later use the website or the app to parse the given text file at given location to display it